# Can't submit a csrf token using javascript in Django

Tags: python, django, axios, csrf, wagtail

I'm using the following code to submit a csrf token purely in js since I want to cache the pages with the form.

```
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFTOKEN'
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

This works locally (localhost, 127.0.0.1) without a problem. This is to get rid of the 403 errors that happen when I login into the app and try to submit a form that no longer has a csrf token embedded in the dom. The issue is I can't get this run in our development environment. The development environment uses CloudFront but i don't think that's an issue. Here is my dev config for Wagtail + Django:

```
#Important for CloudFront
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True

# Security Headers
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 63072000
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True

PREPEND_WWW = False
```

All my API views have `csrf_exempt` on them, but i still need the token when i try to submit after a login. My middleware is:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "app.site_translation.middleware.TranslationMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "app.base.middleware.AdditionalSecurityHeadersMiddleware",
    "app.base.middleware.CookieMiddleware",
    "app.base.middleware.DomainRedirectMiddleware",
    "app.base.middleware.CustomRedirectMiddleware",
    "app.base.middleware.LegacyURLsMiddleware",
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
]
```

I don't know what is going on I keep getting `CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set` in dev but my request clearly has the header and the token: `x-csrftoken: S51NxaQVxJMcRBhlED48np2tajxxUHGC6VQ4463EChJ9GeGRukEqxlD8mnii2RGk`. Also, i mentioned that this works locally like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue csrftoken cookie wasn't being forwarded by CloudFront.